# Twitter bootstrap wrong position on the middle of the element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm placing some html elements in the page through ajax calls, so I'm calling the tooltips like so:

```
$(document).on('hover','.has-tooltip',function(){
    $(this).tooltip('show');
});
```

I've tried also with this:

```
$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[rel=tooltip]'
});
```

But the problem persists.

The problem is that the tooltip is displayed exactly in the middle of the firing element, instead of next to it's outer border.

The annoying thing is that in this way the tooltip hides partially the firing element.

Is it possible that it's the fact that the tooltips are called with `.on()` that is causing the problem?

Any solution? How could I tweak the distance from the element to which the tooltip show?

Here's the HTML

```
<a 
    style="display:block" 
    data-placement="left" 
    data-original-title="Add" 
    class="has-tooltip pull-right icon-black" 
    rel="tooltip" href="#"
>
<i class="icon-plus"></i> 
</a>
```

Comment: Show us your html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it was a bootstrap bug. I have updated to 2.3.1 and the problem is (partially) resolved (it still occurs in some occasions, but I have no idea why).

Change log for 2.3.1 says:

```
fix delegated data-attrs for popover/tooltip
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you attach the tooltips on your ajax calls success?

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(){
        $('.has-tooltip').tooltip();
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

In your first code, you are using `hover` event which does not exists. Instead, you must use `mouseenter` or `mouseover` events.

In your second code, you are adding `tooltip()` to `body` tag instead of your link.

I changed your code  to the following and now it's working. You can see a live demonstration [here](http://jsfiddle.net/faridv/HV33T/):

```
$('body').delegate('a.has-tooltip', 'mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).tooltip('show');
});
```

Feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: Sorry for the errors in the question's code, anyway that was working (I just misspelled here), so the tooltip actually show up.
The problem is that when they show up the do in the wrong place (i.e. in the middle of the firing element), also with your code. I guess there must be a conflict with some code somewhere.. Since I can't post all my css an js, do you have any suggestion on where to look first? Thank's!

Comment: @ghego1 Can you use jsfiddle to show me all of your js?
I guess you are putting the code in the wrong place